# Office Communicator load previous conversation

Tags: history, office-communicator-2007

How can I make Office Communicator 2007 R2 load some portion or number of previous conversations with the current person in the conversation into the Office Communicator window?

For example, if I double click Joe Smith, how can I make sure that the conversation we had yesterday is loaded in the current conversation? Currently it loads a blank screen like below.

[image: Blank Communicator Conversation]

Comment: if you closed the chat window, there's no way to do it.

Comment: @Sathya Will something similar be included in later versions/Lync?

Comment: @RyanGates Lync connects to Outlook 2013 and will create a folder called Conversation History. It will group all the chat lines as items in that folder.

Comment: @sunk818 my question is not how to open the conversation history but how to view the history in the conversation without going through Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

[How to display Communicator 2007 Chat History](http://www.ehow.com/how_7322408_display-chat-history-microsoft-communicator.html)

- Click the top-left status button to open the drop-down menu.
- Click Tools > Options
- Go to the Personal tab
- Check on **Save my instant message conversations in the Outlook Conversation History folder**
- Click OK
- Click Connect, then click **Sign Out** to log out
- Log back in the application

Your conversations will now be stored.

Also, see here on [Finding previos IM Conversations](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Find-Previous-IM-Conversations-38b67421-2bdd-40b9-90b5-f83ac3b25bf5?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: my question is not how to open the conversation history but how to view the history in the conversation without going through Outlook.

Comment: At least in Lync, you have to turn this on, log out, log back in, have a conversation with someone, close the conversation, then go back the person you chatted with to see the conversation history with a grey background. Have you tried what I just described?

Comment: What versions of Lync will this work with? I am currently using Office Communicator 2007 R2 rather than Lync.

Comment: I tested with Lync that comes with Office 2013 Professional. You can get [Lync Basic 32-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35451) here. May not be the same bundled with Office 2013 Pro, but may give you the conversation history and the chat log to appear on screen when chatting with that person again.